# Elasticsearch aggregations slows down over time

Tags: elasticsearch

When trying to query with multiple aggregations in a loop the query-time get really slow.
The result should give me the count from each type.

The JSON i send looks like this

`GET events / _search {
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "count_by_types_38": {
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "data.campaign_id": 38
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "field": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "_type",
                        "min_doc_count": 0
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "count_by_types_39": {
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "data.campaign_id": 39
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "field": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "_type",
                        "min_doc_count": 0
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "count_by_types_40": {
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "data.campaign_id": 40
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "field": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "_type",
                        "min_doc_count": 0
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "count_by_types_41": {
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "data.campaign_id": 41
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "field": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "_type",
                        "min_doc_count": 0
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "count_by_types_42": {
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "data.campaign_id": 42
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "field": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "_type",
                        "min_doc_count": 0
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "count_by_types_44": {
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "data.campaign_id": 44
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "field": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "_type",
                        "min_doc_count": 0
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "count_by_types_45": {
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "data.campaign_id": 45
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "field": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "_type",
                        "min_doc_count": 0
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "count_by_types_46": {
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "data.campaign_id": 46
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "field": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "_type",
                        "min_doc_count": 0
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "count_by_types_47": {
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "data.campaign_id": 47
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "field": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "_type",
                        "min_doc_count": 0
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "count_by_types_48": {
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "data.campaign_id": 48
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "field": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "_type",
                        "min_doc_count": 0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }
}`

For each iteration in the loop i change the data.campaign_id.

I have tried with a lower number of aggregations, and it doesn't really change anything.

8-12 iterations in it takes about 40 seconds before ES returns the result, and i kill it.

If i run the query with just one aggregation there is no problem.

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you checked the state of your JVM?

Comment: A GET _nodes gives me

"mem": {
     "heap_init_in_bytes": 268435456,
     "heap_max_in_bytes": 259719168,
     "non_heap_init_in_bytes": 24313856,
     "non_heap_max_in_bytes": 224395264,
     "direct_max_in_bytes": 259719168
}

Comment: I'm talking more about the log of htop or a monitoring tool

Comment: Ok. My head-plugin says "cluster health: yellow (18 of 52)".
I can't really figure out why it's yellow

Comment: It's yellow because you are not using your replicas yet. If you wish to disable replicas you can specifies that when you are creating your index. Of course disabling replicas has it's consequences.

Comment: But does it matters if it yellow?
Is it what slows the process down?

Comment: The cluster health has nothing to do with the speed of processing. It just means that if one of your shards is down, the data within the shard is lost cause you didn't replicate it into the replica

Comment: You probably want to tune in memory caches for things like the field data cache. Especially the field data cache might cause your jvm to run out of memory eventually. The yellow status is because you apparently specified 2 replicas for your shards and there's only one node in your cluster which means two thirds of your shards (i.e. the replicas) are not available. Fire up two extra nodes to fix that or change the replica setting.

Comment: Great. Thanks. I ran some tests on my server, and the problems went away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my dev server was to small.